# Python sort list of tuples by first value of tuple except for special case

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Hey I have a list of tuples that looks something like:

`[(5, "dummmy_string1"), (6, "dummy_string2"), (3, "special_string")]`

I want to order this in ascending order of the first value of the tuple, except for the case where the string is equal to `special_string`. I want `special_string` to be ordered last regardless of the integer value in the tuple.

I have this right now which doesn't seem to be working:

`sorted(li, key=lambda x: (x.string_value == "special_string", x.int_value))`

I could easily find all the tuples that have `special_string`, remove them from the list, sort the list, and then append them to the end, but looking for a cleaner solution.

EDIT:

I made a silly mistake and realized that my solution does work...=)

Comment: Your code should work, but only if you have named tuples. You can just use `(x[1] == "special_string", x[0])` as the sort value. How is it not working for you?

Comment: what about the case of `[(4,"A"),(4,"B")]` do you want it to move onto the second value in the event that the first value is a tie? (and the second value is not your `"special_string"`

Comment: Martijn you are correct, it does work. I accidentally reversed the order in my named tuple when I was testing in the interpreter, which screwed it up. 

Joran, I don't care about that tie when ti doesn't involve special string.

Comment: Dear @AtulBhatia Could you please add your silly mistake as an answer (of course in a better manner) instead of adding that to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [(5, "dummmy_string1"), (6, "dummy_string2"), (3, "special_string")]
print sorted(li,key=lambda x:(x[-1]=="special_string",)+x)
```

should work fine ... no idea what you `x.string_value` is (other than perhaps an `AttributeError`)

in the event there are several `special_string`'s it will sort them in the same order as the other strings (that is standard Left2Right tuple sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Since sort is stable you can just sort the list twice.  Once for the first key and then a second time for the special case

```
In [2]: li = [(5, "dummmy_string1"), (6, "dummy_string2"), (3, "special_string")]

In [3]: sorted(li, key = lambda x : x[0])
Out[3]: [(3, 'special_string'), (5, 'dummmy_string1'), (6, 'dummy_string2')]

In [4]: sorted(li, key = lambda x : x[1] == "special_string")
Out[4]: [(5, 'dummmy_string1'), (6, 'dummy_string2'), (3, 'special_string')]
```

Comment: @Joran True, this will likely be slower.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted in the question does indeed work:

`sorted(li, key=lambda x: (x.string_value == "special_string", x.int_value))`